# Creating multiple rectangles using SDL_Rect

Tags: c, sdl

I'm creating a simulation for Conway's game of life using C and SDL. To represent the alive cells I would like to create multiple rectangles in the window which I have created. Is there any way to call SDL_Rect in a for loop without redefintion of SDL_Rect and output the result of the for loop all on the same renderer? Thank you.

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#define main SDL_main
#undef main

double CreateRectanglesX()
{   
    double x; double x_max = 640; double x_min = 20;
    x = rand() / (x_max - x_min) / (double)RAND_MAX + x_min;
    return x;
}

double CreateRectanglesY()
{
    double y; double y_max = 480; double y_min = 20; 
    y = rand() / (y_max - y_min) / (double)RAND_MAX + y_min;
    return y; 
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO); //initializes the SDL/SDL2 window

    SDL_Window *screen; //SDL window created with pointer 
    screen = SDL_CreateWindow("My Program Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL); 
    //definition for pointer - dimensions of SDL window

    SDL_Renderer *renderer; //Renderer created with pointer
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(screen, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED); //definition for pointer - still to learn

    if (screen == NULL) //checks if window exists or not
    {
        printf("Could not create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError()); //returns error if window doesn't exsit
        return 1;
    } 

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255); //changes color of renderer
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer); 
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer); //displays the renderer with the changed color

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        double x = CreateRectanglesX();
        double y = CreateRectanglesY();
        printf("%lf %lf", x, y);
        SDL_Rect a;
        a.x = x;
        a.y = y;
        a.w = 20;
        a.h = 20;
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 255, 255);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &a);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    SDL_Delay(5000); //wait time for window
    SDL_DestroyWindow(screen);
    SDL_QUIT;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: " //all appropriate includes are there", please type them for us and make a [mcve].

Comment: Please elaborate what keeps you from doing exactly as you described: Use the code which you currently use to make one rectangle inside a loop to do several. You are aware which code that is, aren't you? Can you highlight that part of the code, e.g. with comments "rectangle start" and "rectangle end"?

Comment: The code you show demonstrates how you successfully create a single rectangle, doesn't it? Could you show your (unsuccessful) attempt to create multiple? Try to make a [mcve] of that.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake was the fact that my random number generation formula with CreateRectanglesX() and CreateRectanglesY was wrong. It was

```
v = rand() / (x_max - x_min) / RAND_MAX + x_min;
```

Should have been:

```
v = rand() * (x_max - x_min) / RAND_MAX + x_min;
```

Only one rectangle was being displayed because the random numbers being produced with the random generation function were too close (due to wrong formula). Fixing the formula resolved the issue!